# Migrations and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, migration

I have a simple question.  I want to start using CodeIgniter migrations.  But there is no migrations.php file in my config folder, like it says in the documentation.  Also, do I need to manually create the migrations folder at the application folder level?

Comment: I even downloaded the latest version, 2.1.2, but it's not there.

Comment: Here's the docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html

Comment: Weird, the file is on the GitHub stable branch, but isn't in the download.

Comment: the best alternative is download the CI archive by githug, because for some reason the CI archive from codeignter.com comes with bugs (and old versions too). However, if migration file does not exist you can import it into libraries folder with no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's odd that your `application/config/migration.php` file wasn't included in the download, however... Even though the config file isn't there, the migration library will (or should) still be in your CodeIgniter `system/libraries` folder.

There are three config variables as part of the default `migration.php` config file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable/Disable Migrations
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Migrations are disabled by default but should be enabled 
| whenever you intend to do a schema migration.
|
*/
$config['migration_enabled'] = FALSE;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migrations version
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is used to set migration version that the file system should be on.
| If you run $this->migration->latest() this is the version that schema will
| be upgraded / downgraded to.
|
*/
$config['migration_version'] = 0;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migrations Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Path to your migrations folder.
| Typically, it will be within your application path.
| Also, writing permission is required within the migrations path.
|
*/
$config['migration_path'] = APPPATH . 'migrations/';
```